# Specify a template name in class based View

Tags: django, django-views

I am new to Django and trying to work from [django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload)

It has introduced me to class based Views.

I'm trying to replicate one of these class based views to contain a share link that will refer back to individual links in the gallery.

the class i'm trying to adapt is:

```
class PictureDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Picture

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    This does not actually delete the file, only the database record. But
    that is easy to implement.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    self.object.delete()
    if request.is_ajax():
        response = JSONResponse(True, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload/new')

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSON response class."""
    def __init__(self,obj='',json_opts={},mimetype="application/json",*args,**kwargs):
        content = simplejson.dumps(obj,**json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse,self).__init__(content,mimetype,*args,**kwargs)
```

This defaults to the template name picture_confirm_delete.html

How can i rewrite a class with the same functionality except that it points to a different template? or better still & in keeping with 'DRY' how can i reuse this class on another template?

I've had a look over the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/) but can't seem to adapt it to my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, here's what's happening currently: a [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) in Django will render a default template based on the class name as explained in the docs:

> The `DeleteView` page displayed to a GET request uses a `template_name_suffix` of `'_confirm_delete'`.

To change this, just overrule this behaviour by providing the [`template_name` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name):

> `template_name`
>
> The full name of a template to use as defined by a string.

This works for any built-in class based view inheriting from a TemplateResponseMixin.

Apply it in the class definition *or* in the URL patterns (whichever you prefer):

- In the class:

  ```
  class MyOwnPictureDeleteView(PictureDeleteView):
      template_name = "myown_picture_delete_template.html"
  ```

  Yes, that's your complete new class based view.

  **or**
- In URLconf:

  ```
  url(r'^picture_delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/', 'myapp.views.PictureDeleteView', \
  {'template_name': 'myown_picture_delete_template.html'}),
  ```

Either way, you don't have to rewrite a single line of the original PictureDeleteView class, so this is as DRY as it gets.

Comment: So i ended up duplicating the same class and changing the name and adding the template_name as you desrcibed, but would there not been a more 'DRY' way to achieve the same?

Comment: @ChristopherCamplin I think I just showed in the example you don't have to duplicate code - just use class inheritance as seen in my answer (`class MyOwnPictureDeleteView(PictureDeleteView)`).

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood what you were trying to say, that worked like a charm, many thanks.

Comment: Warning: If the template you specify with `template_name` doesn’t exist, Django will use the default instead of raising an error.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`DeleteView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/) also inherits from [`SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.detail/SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin/) it requires a template and therefore a template name.

But since you are not really using the functionality provided by Django's `DeleteView` but creating you own by using the HTTP method `DELETE` you can just change the parent class of your view from `DeleteView` to `View`.

Otherwise check which functionality from which of `DeleteView`'s ancesctors you need, [this](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a good starting point for browsing class-based views (the official Django documentation isn't really yet).